# Create a Base TagHelper with no TargetElement

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm creating a library of MVC6 TagHelpers for a large project.

I find myself writing certain functionality in these TagHelpers again and again.

I'd like to make a base TagHelper that all the others inherit from to remove all the duplicated code.

The issue is this - suppose I create a base TagHelper as below:

```
public class BaseTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        //Some implementation...
    }
}
```

Now, when I go to write a view, I will have intellisense suggesting the taghelper `<base>`.

Is there any way I can tell intellisense that this isn't a TagHelper I actually want to use, just a base class containing implementation common to other TagHelpers I've created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create it as an `abstract` class, see some examples in the official MVC Core repo like [CacheTagHelperBase](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/CacheTagHelperBase.cs)

```
public abstract class BaseTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        //Some base implementation...
    }
}
```